# Issue with DateDiff / Nb in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, datediff

When I use a `DateDiff` in a `SELECT` statement in SQL Server, I get an `int` value back:

```
select DATEDIFF(day,'01/01/2011','15/05/2011') 
from Table1
```

Result is : `134`

```
select DATEDIFF(day,'01/01/2011','15/05/2011')/15 
from Table1
```

Result is : `8`

```
select cast(DATEDIFF(day,'01/01/2011','15/05/2011') / 15 as Decimal(9,2)) 
from Table1
```

Result is : `8.00`

But in reality the result is : **8.9333333**

How can I change the result from `int` to `Double`?

I want to get the result `8.9333333` - how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `CAST` after dividing. If you perform the division after the `CAST`, you'll get the answer you want:

```
select 
   cast(DATEDIFF(day,'01/01/2011','15/05/2011') as Decimal(9,2))/15 
from Table1
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast your inputs into the division as decimal first:

```
select cast(DATEDIFF(day,'2011-01-01','2011-05-15') as Decimal(9,2))/15.0
```

Otherwise you are dividing an integer by an integer - you'll get an integer out.  If you then cast this to a decimal after the division, you are going to get 8.0.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(day,'01/01/2011','15/05/2011') AS Decimal(9,2))/15 
FROM Table1
```

Comment: Thanks all , all your answers are correct :)